# Determine turn taking in game

Tags: android

I am creating a game and I would highly appreciate any advise on this.

I have an activity which loads a class and as that class is loaded, the text view would shows player 1 turn. I understand I can set this in the xml.

But then when player 1 loses the game the text field should show player 2 turn.

It would be great if someone could explain how I could do this.

Even better would be if two people could enter there names one as player 1 and then as player 2 which would then show the names of whose turn it is.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Dont set the text in the xml file. Since your app is supposed to set the text dynamically

2) Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html). You can use setText() to dispay the desired text.

Code to get the TextView

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextviewid)
```

It would help if you read a book on android programming before starting game programming

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that was not what I was looking for. I know I can create a variable which calls the textview and from that variable I can set the text. In the game so far when the user has clicked the button a certain amount of times they lose. From this I would like to know how to determine turn taking.

Comment: That totally depends on the logic of the game. Keep a track of the number of times Player1 clicked a button. [Use the buttons OnClick listener](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html). Or whenever the player [loses the game](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/The_Game) just switch the text, and start a new game.

Comment: The game is a 2 player game from which one user enters a word and then this jumbles with onClick. player 2 then tries to guess the word. I have created this up to where the player guesses the word and can only guess 5 times using a flag variable. The text is then set to lost if guessed wrong 5 times. I could switch text when its a new game but I want to add score taking which would carry on the game until a user quits. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you meant there. This is not what you asked in the original question. I suggest you start coding. [You can use SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to keep track of global scores.